# How to get the Values of Edit Text dynamically whose values should match up with already existing values in a table?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sqlite

For example, assume it:

In a question paper, I have to write the answer for given questions but there is no choice available. So overall I am attending all the questions. My answers might be a wrong or correct. It should be able to match up with the known answers already existing in a another table.

Then result will be like this, my answers and already existing correct known answers will be display in a page.

So probably I can know it for such particular questions which one is correct answer and wrongly I opted so could able to check about my capabilities.

So question is TextView and answer is EditText. If I write answer on EditText it should be able to check my answer with existing correct answers in a table.

How could i do this programmatically on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get EditText value which user enter by using following in Button onclick event.

```
    String value=edittext.gettext().toString();
if(value.equals(sqlitevalue))
{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Match !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**OR**

You can also check on Text Changed Event.

Comment: Thankyou so much ! But why could not able to type inside the EditBox like any text? Typing words are not visible properly. Cursor is not at correct position. Why so?

Comment: Also when i do debug, it is showing me as null. In this line "if(value.equals(sqlitevalue))" . Could anyone tell me please ?

Comment: value or sqlitevalue one of is null at that time it give you error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `editText.getText().toString()` to get text in the answer field.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(edittext.getText().toString().trim().equals(correctanswer))
{
   Toast.makeText(this,"Answer is Correct",20).show();
}
```